# proof if vectors are linearly independent then they are not parallel

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

## Problem

Show that if vectors $(\overline{v},\overline{w}) \in V$ are linearly independent and neither of them is zero vector then they are not parallel

## Attempt to show by contrapositive

Vectors $(\vec{v},\vec{w})$ are parallel when

$$ \exists(a,b) \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} : a \vec{v}= b\vec{w} $$

$$ \iff a \vec{v} - b \vec{w} = \vec{0} $$

By definition vectors $(\vec{v},\vec{w})$ are linearly dependent if

$$ ( \exists{c_1,c_2} \in \mathbb{R} : c_1 \vec{v} + c_2 \vec{w} = \vec{0} ) \wedge (c_1 \vee c_2 \neq 0) $$

Then let $c_1 = a, c_2 = -b$ then we have

$$ a\vec{v}-b\vec{w} \iff c_1 \vec{v} + c_2 \vec{w} = \vec{0} $$

---

Do I have any flaws in this?

Comment: In the first line, you should have $\exists$ and not $\forall$.  And I think you mean $(a,b)\in \mathbb R^2-(0,0)$.

Comment: Really though, this is a duplicate of [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3321379/show-that-if-vectors-overlinev-overlinew-in-v-are-linearly-independen) and the answers provided there seem complete.

Comment: @lulu yes first line has typo

Comment: You should have $a,b\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$

Comment: Your edit only fixed one of the two errors I pointed out.

Comment: @lulu I didn't quite get the answer I got on last post I made. For example I'm not sure what he means by scalar field.

Comment: So, ask a question of that user.  I expect that in the context you have in mind, "scalar field" just means $\mathbb R$.  But, really, you should ask the person who posted the solution.

Comment: @lulu Aside from typos and change to notation how my answer seems?

Comment: Well, I don't care for that definition of parallel.  I'd say that two non-zero vectors, $\vec v, \vec u$ are parallel when there exists a scalar $\lambda $ such that $\vec v =\lambda \vec u$.  I think that handles degenerate cases better.  In your definition, you'd have $\vec 0$ at least parallel to itself, which I would not allow.  But other than that I think you are ok.